# makefile shell and pipe

Tags: shell, makefile, pipe

I need help: the following command line is not working

```
TESTS := $(shell cat test_cases_file | egrep -v ^\s*(#|$) ) 
all: $(TESTS)
```

when I launch:

```
make all
```

I get an error something like "call of shell command is not finished."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing quotes in `egrep` parameter. If I were `make` I'd too believe that # is the beginning of comment.

Apparently simply adding quotes won't help, you'll need to escape the `#` too.

edit:
Actually `$` has to be escaped too and in case of `make` it is done using `$$`

Try this:

```
TESTS := $(shell egrep -v '^\s*(\#|$$)' test_cases_file) 
all: $(TESTS)
```

Finally, you don't really need to discard blank lines - that won't hurt:

```
TESTS := $(shell egrep -v '^\s*\#' test_cases_file) 
all: $(TESTS)
```

Comment: Why did I not see the second part of your answer before my last post !
Anyway thank you all.
Would you please suggest a good tutorial on makefile if you know any.

Answer (score 0):

What you've stumbled upon is probably the fact, that parentheses are not escapeable in GNU Make.

You can work around this problem by using helper script:

```
TESTS := $(shell ./grep.sh test_cases_file )
all: $(TESTS)
```

Where `grep.sh` is:

```
cat $1 | egrep -v ^\s*(#|$)
```

Comment: I believe it was said somewhere... Why `cat` at all? `egrep -v '^\s*(#|$)' $1` which makes the whole `grep.sh` unnecessary`

Comment: @aragaer - I just happen to use `cat` with `grep`. Why? Ususally it's a little bit faster to change grep's expresion, when it's at the end of the line ;)

Comment: Thks!
is there any other way to avoid adding **grep.sh** file ?
@aragaer can you please explain how to escape #


**PS.** what I am trying here is generate all targets depending on input file lines (if starts with # or empty => don't generate)

Comment: I found the solution.
`$$ to get $ and  \# to get #`
so I wrote:

`TESTS := $(shell cat test_cases_file | egrep -v "^\s*(\#|$$)" )`

Thks.